# Accessing table data frequently

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read a table from a worksheet and storing in an listobject. I need to use this table data multiple time and **I dont want to access worksheet every time I need table data**. I think accessing worksheet everytime will slow down the performance. 
Also I need to refer table data based on header name. 
I was thinking of writing something like this.

```
public Tbl_MyTable  as listobject
public Arr as variant
Set Tbl_MyTable = Workbooks("Myworkbook").worksheets("Myworksheet").ListObjects("Tbl1")
tRows = Tbl_MyTable .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
for i=1 to 10
      config= ArrConfig(i)
      call readtable(tRows, config)
      Set Destination = workbooks("x").sheets("y").Range("A2")
      Destination.Resize(1,UBound(Arr, 1)).Value = Arr  
      'Create the table based on the populated data.
      Set populated_area = Destination.CurrentRegion
      Set Create_Table = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, populated_area, , xlYes)
      Create_Table.name = (.name & "_tbl")
      Create_Table.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15" 
      'Select this newly created table and do some data reformating
      With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("" & Tbl_name & "").Range.Select 
          'Change entire Table font
       With Selection.Font
        .name = "Calibri Light"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMajor
    End With
End with
...
...
...

'Inside Sub readtable
For i = 1 To tRows
if config= A
     Arr(i) = Range("Tbl_MyTable[Header1]")(i).Value
else if config =B
     Arr(i) = Range("Tbl_MyTable[Header2]")(i).Value
else 
     Arr(i) = Range("Tbl_MyTable[Header3]")(i).Value
end if
.
.
```

Problem is that it works only for first iteration of top level loop.
Next time I get following error (Somehow I am getting multiple errors every time I run it. Not all appear everytime)

```
Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed
Error number: 90 Subscript out of range
```

Any idea what might be wrong here. I guess looking this code again and again I am hitting a wall now. I need another set of eyes to help me.

Comment: More code would be helpful... though I'm not sure why you're looping at all.

Comment: Once you've read the data from the sheet, what do you need to do with it?  You can read the whole table range into an array using `arr = Workbooks("Myworkbook").worksheets("Myworksheet").ListObjects("Tbl1").Range.Value`  No need for a loop.

Comment: Added some more details to the code.Basically in outer loop I set some conditions which are passed in inner loop. Based on these conditions I need to pick only selected values from the table. Values from the table needs to be picked based on header names. Hope this clarifies my intention.

Comment: Added further details. Before  iteration of the first loop, I go to some other worksheet and write the data and convert that into a table there. Then I resume my loop and start reading my input table again. But this time get the error. Is it because I dealt with some other table and now I have to reload my input table again from input worksheet inorder to be able to use the data?